# Fastest way to combine unique integers from 2 arrays

Tags: java, performance

If I have the 2 arrays:

```
arr1 = {9,8}
arr2 = {13,12,10,9,8}
```

I'd like to get:

```
{13,12,10}
```

And given the arrays:

```
arr1 = {23,22,21,20,19,18,17,16}
arr2 = {21,17}
```

The result will be:

```
{23,22,20,19,18,16}
```

So basically I'm obtaining the numbers that are either in arr1 or arr2, but not both.

- The 2 arrays may be of different lengths.
- The 2 arrays are sorted in descending order, and the final array must also have this property.
- This is done millions of times, so I'm trying to reduce/prevent object allocations as best as I can. This is why I'm not using sets to do the job.

Comment: Please add homework tag if this is a homework question.

Comment: So basically you want to remove the intersection of the two lists from the union of the two lists?

Comment: @Korhan, this is not a homework. :)

Comment: do you want to get [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) e.g., [in Python](http://ideone.com/ImGiq)?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Yes. Oh I LOVE Python and the simplicity of its code. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the EXOR of the two sets. I think this is simpler than it looks, due to the arrays being pre-sorted. Pseudo-code

> 1. compare the first element from each array
> 2. if unequal, add the larger one to the unique set
> 3. else remove both elements
> 4. if you've reached the end of one array, add all the elements remaining in the other array to the unique set

which is a [greedy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greedy_algorithm) O(n) solution. Here's an implementation, lightly tested :D

```
/**
 * Returns the sorted EXOR of two sorted int arrays (descending). Uses
 * arrays, index management, and System.arraycopy.
 * @author paislee
 */
int[] arrExor(int[] a1, int[] a2) {

    // eventual result, intermediate (oversized) result
    int[] exor, exor_builder = new int[a1.length + a2.length];
    int exor_i = 0; // the growing size of exor set

    int a1_i = 0, a2_i = 0; // input indices
    int a1_curr, a2_curr; // elements we're comparing

    // chew both input arrays, greedily populating exor_builder
    while (a1_i < a1.length && a2_i < a2.length) {

        a1_curr = a1[a1_i];
        a2_curr = a2[a2_i];

        if (a1_curr != a2_curr) {
            if (a1_curr > a2_curr)
                exor_builder[exor_i++] = a1[a1_i++];
            else
                exor_builder[exor_i++] = a2[a2_i++];
        } else {
            a1_i++;
            a2_i++;
        }        
    }

    // copy remainder into exor_builder
    int[] left = null; // alias for the unfinished input
    int left_i = 0, left_sz = 0; // index alias, # elements left

    if (a1_i < a1.length) {
        left = a1;
        left_i = a1_i;
    } else {
        left = a2;
        left_i = a2_i;
    }

    left_sz = left.length - left_i;
    System.arraycopy(left, left_i, exor_builder, exor_i, left_sz);
    exor_i += left_sz;

    // shrinkwrap and deliver
    exor = new int[exor_i];
    System.arraycopy(exor_builder, 0, exor, 0, exor_i);
    return exor;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you have the arrays in sorted order, the overlap between them is important - you can process the non-overlapping portions very fast from a single array without checking the other one.

```
9 8 7 5
     6 4 3 2
```

E.g. 9,8,7 can be taken directly from array 1, then the middle section needs more care, then you can take 4,3,2 directly from array 2. It would help to know whether the non-overlapping portions of your inputs are likely to be significant or not.

For the middle section, you just need to repeatedly take the maximum of the next unprocessed element from each array (and remove duplicates).

You will need an array for the results - one approach is to allocate an array big enough to hold both of the input arrays, as a worst case, then either do a `System.arrayCopy()` into a new array of the right size, or just keep a count of the number of actual elements. Another approach is to use an `ArrayList` and do a `toarray` afterwards if desired.

Comment: Maybe BitSets can be of some use as well. I should test whether the logic a BitSet needs out ways the if-else checks needed by this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want to use a merge sort.  Usually it is used to merge ascending lists, but it can be descending as well.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort

Since you have two sorted collections, the merge is O(n)

Answer (score 0):

Use Sets, but reuse them and empty them out at the beginning of each iteration. OR, since the arrays are guaranteed to be sorted, you could use something comparable to a merge. (Maintain an index into both arrays. At each step, if the 2 indexes are pointing to equal elements, move the indexes past those elements, and don't add anything to the output. Otherwise, add the larger element to the output, and advance that index only.)